# javascript pull values from multiple functions

Tags: javascript, function

I'm practicing with event listeners and functions and am trying to build a very simple card game. My first 2 functions work to get values of card 1 and 2 once the respective buttons are clicked. I've built a third to combine the total, but having trouble pulling the generated values into a third function. My third function always returns zero. I get why, but haven't been able to find a solution to pull the values from the first 2 functions. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
var cardButton = document.getElementById('cardButton1');
  var cardButton2 = document.getElementById('cardButton2');
  var cardValue = document.getElementById('cardValue');
  var cardValue2 = document.getElementById('cardValue2');
  var cardTotalButton = document.getElementById('cardTotalButton');
  var cardTotal = document.getElementById('displayTotal');
  var card1Value = 0;
  var card2Value = 0;
  var totalCardsValue = 0;
  var cardMin = 1;
  var cardMax = 14;


  function generateCard(){
    var card1Value = randCard();
    cardValue.innerHTML = 'card value is ' + card1Value;
    return card1Value;
  }

  function generateCard2(){
    var card2Value = randCard();
    cardValue2.innerHTML = 'card value is ' + card2Value;
    return card2Value;
  }

  function getPlayerTotal(){
    var totalCardsValue = card1Value + card2Value;
    //console.log(cardValue2 + 'test');
    cardTotal.innerHTML = 'card total is ' + totalCardsValue;

  }

cardButton.addEventListener('click',generateCard);
cardButton2.addEventListener('click',generateCard2);
cardTotalButton.addEventListener('click',getPlayerTotal);



function randCard(){
  var genRandCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*cardMax)+1;
  return genRandCard;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `generateCard*`? What are you doing with the return values? You have to assign them to something...

Comment: Thanks again this worked. I'm not using the return I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring your `card1Value`, `card2Value`, and `totalCardsValue` to a local scope. Remove the `var` in front of them. Doing it this way, you don't need to return any value from the `generateCard()` and `generateCard()` function because you're using the global variables.

```
  function generateCard(){
    card1Value = randCard(); //<-------Don't use var here
    cardValue.innerHTML = 'card value is ' + card1Value;
    return card1Value; //<-------This line is not really needed
  }

  function generateCard2(){
    card2Value = randCard(); //<-------Don't use var here
    cardValue2.innerHTML = 'card value is ' + card2Value;
    return card2Value; //<-------This line is not really needed
  }

  function getPlayerTotal(){
    totalCardsValue = card1Value + card2Value;  //<-------Don't use var here
    //console.log(cardValue2 + 'test');
    cardTotal.innerHTML = 'card total is ' + totalCardsValue;
  }
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks you!